# Subalgebra of an F-algebra

Tags: category-theory

In the literature for F-algebras there appears frequently the notion of F-subalgebra. I'm trying to interpret this as some kind of subobject in the category of all F-algebras and F-algebras homomorphisms.

Is my interpretation right? What would be the right way to encode it?

Comment: Hm, doesn't there exist a monomorphism from the subalgebra to the corresponding algebra making it a subobject in the category of $F$-algebras?

Comment: @QiZhu I see. My definitions would say that there has to be an equivalence class of injections from the (sub)algebra to the algebra. We don't get rid of the equivalence class right?

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, I guess we should say that the subobjects correspond to the isomorphism classes of the subalgebras. Someone more experienced than me should verify this, though. (In Vahil, $A$ is a subobject of $B$ if there exists a monomorphism $A \to B$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reference taken from Universal Algebra and Coalgebra from Denecke and Wismath point 5.3:

> Let $\mathcal{A} = (A,\beta_A)$ be an $F$-algebra and $S \subseteq A$.
>
> The set $S$ is said to be closed if htere is a mapping $\beta_S:F(S) \to S$ such that the embedding (injection) mapping $i: S \to A$ is a homomorphism.

In this case, $\mathcal{S} = (S,\beta_S)$ is called a subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$.